# SQL: “The maximum number of stacked diagnostics areas has been exceeded.”

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

The following formula in my `SELECT` text yields the aforementioned error when attempting to refresh.

```
SELECT CAPCSQ/((((ih01su + ih02su + ih03su + ih04su + ih05su + ih06su + ih07su + ih08su + ih09su + ih10su + ih11su + ih12su)/12)*1.32)/2)
```

The `ih01su....` portion represents the last 12 months of sales data, divided by 12 to get an average. I then multiply by the 1.32 to get a projection of future sales in roughly 2 years based on store growth. I then divided by 2 because I really only want the value that will be 2 weeks worth of sales, not a full month.

The formula works fine until I attempt to divide the ‘`CAPCSQ`’ column by this calculated value.  At this point I get the following error:

> The maximum number of stacked diagnostics areas has been exceeded.

Comment: What database are you using?  Almost sounds like too many arithmetic operations or something.

Comment: I am pulling from an AS400 database into Excel.

Comment: Are you calling this from within a stored procedure or some other programming unit? The stacked diagnostics message seems to be related somehow with rollbacks or some error handling.  Are you able to run the query just by itself?  Very little details on the message if you go here and search for 'stacked diagnostics'  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzala/rzalaml.htm

Comment: Hey msturek. I’m sorry if I’m not knowledgeable enough to respond correctly. This is part of a larger query, with many more columns, all of which work fine until the above selection is added. With all other columns eliminated and just the above selection remaining, the error is as mentioned. Could you clarify you question further? I’m grateful for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you did what I was asking - I was trying to isolate just that one section of the query.  I'm afraid I'm not knowledgeable on db2 issues and this stacked diagnostic seems to be some specific to its architecture, but a generic error.  Hopefully someone who's more knowledgeable on db2 can shed some light.

Comment: Edit your question (don't use comment) to include the SQLCODE or SQLSTATE, and  the Db2 for i  *release*, and  which *driver* you are using on Windows, and the *driver version and bitness*.